# How can I measure brake pad thickness without removing the wheels?

Tags: brake-pad, measurement

Is there a way to measure the pad thickness w/o removing the wheels?

(disc brakes obviously)

Comment: Using a camera phone held near the calliper, you may be able to take a video recording of the pads and get a rough idea of whether they have plenty of lining left on them.

Comment: By "tire" do you mean wheel? You do not need to remover tires , only wheels.

Comment: @blacksmith37 yes sorry wheels. edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accurately measure the pad thickness you will need to remove the tire.  Sometimes the pads wear unevenly - inside pad versus outside pad, as well as across the width and top versus bottom of the pad. It is best to remove the pads and use a caliper to measure the pad thickness. Also, each pad could wear differently so don't assume if you check the front pads on the driver side that the passenger side is the same thickness. To be safe check each of the pads on all four axles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tip I learned while working on furnaces to determine the screw head type on the back of the furnace. Reach back and press your fingertip against the screw head. Then you can look at your fingertip for the impression.

Do this with each pad: reach and press a fingertip against the edge of the pad. You can see or measure the approximate thickness.